# Processing large amounts of Rasters in R

Tags: raster, r

I have 6500 processed and clipped rasters that indicate snow levels on a daily basis in the northern hemisphere. I need to create a raster that represents a sum of the snow for the season. The winter season would then go from September 1999 to march 2000. I was just wondering how I would go about recalling the daily rasters into R using the loop function/ how i would go about calculating the seasonal sums. Keep in mind that the rasters span two different years and that I don't want to include all 1999 snow data because that would include the previous winter(98/99) as well.

Comment: What is the naming system of your files? Do you have to deal with missing files?

Answer (score 5):

Index each day with its year and julian day. September 1 is 244, March 31 is 90. Not knowing the format of your files, you can probably figure out a date format to use to parse and turn it into a POSIX date (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414847/convert-a-date-vector-into-julian-day-in-r):

```
tmp <- as.POSIXlt("16Jun10", format = "%d%b%y")
tmp$yday
```

Assuming you have extracted your dates from filenames:

```
tmp <- as.POSIXlt(myFormattedDates, format = "%d%b%y")
julianDay <- tmp$yday
```

Next, to determine the winter year for each file, take the year and julian day as a 7-digit number (e.g., September 1, 1998 is 1998244 and March 31, 1999 is 1999090), subtract 91, divide by 1000, and take the floor:

```
winterYear <- floor(((year*1000+julianDay)-91)/1000)
```

this assumes you have three vectors with the same length, corresponding to the same rasters:

1. a vector `year` containing the year of all the files
2. a vector `julianDay` containing the julian day of all the files
3. a vector `rasterNames` with the paths to all the rasters.

Next, you can select the files based on the given year:

```
for (year in unique(winterYear)) {
    winterSumRaster <- NULL
    thisWinterRasterNames <- rasterNames[which(winterYear == year)]
    for (winterRasterName in thisWinterRasterNames) {
        dailyRaster <- raster(winterRasterName)
        if (is.null(winterSumRaster)) {
            winterSumRaster <- raster(dailyRaster)
            setValues(winterSumRaster,getValues(dailyRaster))
        } else {
            setValues(winterSumRaster,getValues(dailyRaster)+getValues(winterSumRaster))
        }
    }
    writeRaster(winterSumRaster,paste0("winterSum",year,".grd"))
}
```

You can save the raster in other formats of course, but .grd does not require anything special like `gdal`.

Comment: Nice answer but why the `getValues`, `setValues` approach? Why not just read all the data as a stack, use `which` on the names to create a subset index and then use `calc` with `sum` to derive seasonal sums?

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, I would like to see what you mean. It sounds more elegant than my solution.

Comment: setValues(winterSumRaster,getValues(dailyRaster))  - this is not actually persisted anywhere since there's no assigment

Comment: @mdsumner what's the appropriate method call there?

Comment: I think the call is ok, you just want to assign it somewhere, .i.e. winterSumRaster <- .

Comment: avoid the inner loop. `out <- sum(stack(thisWinterRasterNames))`. Also see this:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151424/i-need-to-create-a-function-in-r-that-processes-rasters-in-esri-grid-format/151507#151507